# What mean the notation $p_{t,s}(x,dy)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In my course (see picture below) (under the formula (0.1.3)), they say that $p_{s,t}(x,dy)$ is a regular version of the conditional probability distribution of $X_t$ given $X_s$. Could someone tell me what does it mean ? Does is mean that $$\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid X_s=x\}=\int_A p_{s,t}(x,dy) \ ?$$

---

[image]

Comment: In this particular situation there isn't really any reason to write it like that rather than as $p_{s,t}(x,A)$, which is a probability measure characterizing the probability of transitioning from a fixed point $x$ to a set $A$ as time goes from $s$ to $t$. In other situations this sort of notation can help with defining more complicated measures.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you. So my interpretation is correct ? i.e. $p_{s,t}(x,A)=\mathbb P\{X_t\in A\mid X_s=x\}=\int_A p_{s,t}(x,dy)$ ?

Comment: That's correct.